# How do I sort a key:list dictionary by values in list?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
mydict = {'name':['peter', 'janice', 'andy'], 'age':[10, 30, 15]}
```

How do I sort this dictionary based on key=="name" list?

End result should be:

```
mydict = {'name':['andy', 'janice', 'peter'], 'age':[15, 30, 10]}
```

Or is dictionary the wrong approach for such data?

Comment: You could instead make a dictionary with the name of a person as the key and the value as their age. However, the only problem with such an arrangement is that there can only be a single person with a given name.

Comment: If name and age are related to a person, I'd recommend using a different structure for your data. Maybe a list of `namedtuple`s?

Comment: dictionary is the right datastructure, but if possible try someting like this `people = { 'andy': {'age': 15}, 'janice': {'age': 30}, 'peter': {'age': 10}}`.

Comment: Try using dictionary like this ``{'peter': 10, 'janice': 30, 'andy': 15}``. Also do you have more attributes for each person (like gender, phone number or anything else about that person)?

Comment: @linluk: and what if there are two people named 'andy'?

Comment: @stranac than you need another approch ;-)
maybe something like `[{'name':'', 'age':1},...]` and sort it like `sorted(people, lambda a,b: a['name'] > b['name'])`

Comment: @stranac or easier: `sorted(people, key=lambda x: x['name'])`

Comment: @linluk or better practice: `sorted(people, key=operator.itemgetter('name'))`

Comment: @All,  I think I need the data in this format, the dataset has lots of other columns similar to a table having lots of rows there could 2 andy's, with different age, etc etc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you manipulate data, often it helps that each column be an observed variable (name, age), and each row be an observation (e.g. a sampled person). More on *tidy data* in this [PDF link](http://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10/v59i10.pdf)

> Bad programmers worry about the code. Good programmers worry about
>   data structures and their relationships - Linus Torvalds

A list of dictionaries lends itself better to operations like this. Below I present a beginner-friendly snippet to tidy your data. Once you have a good data structure, sorting by any variable is trivial even for a beginner. No one-liner Python kung-fu :)

```
>>> mydict = {'name':['peter', 'janice', 'andy'], 'age':[10, 30, 15]}
```

Let's work on a better data structure first

```
>>> persons = []
>>> for i, name in enumerate(mydict['name']):
...     persons.append({'name': name, 'age': mydict['age'][i]})
... 
>>> persons
[{'age': 10, 'name': 'peter'}, {'age': 30, 'name': 'janice'}, {'age': 15, 'name': 'andy'}]
```

Now it's easier to work on this data structure which is similar to "data frames" in data analysis environments. Let's sort it by `person.name`

```
>>> persons = sorted(persons, key=lambda person: person['name'])
```

Now bring it back to your format if you want to

```
>>> {'name': [p['name'] for p in persons], 'age': [p['age'] for p in persons]}
{'age': [15, 30, 10], 'name': ['andy', 'janice', 'peter']}
```

Comment: note that building the dict is probably easier doing `new_dict = [{"name": name, "age": age} for name,age in zip(*mydict.values())]`

Comment: Sure but the op looks to me like a Python beginner, didn't want to intimidate. Also the main take away here is the _tidy data_

Comment: Still zip is not more difficult to understand than enumerate, so use zip: `for name, age in zip(mydict['name'], mydict['age']): persons.append({'name': name, 'age': age})`

Comment: Thanks @bakkal I am a python beginner. Those concepts are really handy, will take it on board.

Comment: could someone elaborate/explain this `key=lambda person:person['name']`

Comment: Think of the lambda there as a function that takes a person and returns the name, used as a `key`  to `sorted()`, it means that you are sorting by the name

Comment: The reason my dict is that way is because I read CSV into a dict. I wrote a snippet to do that: `def createDict(dict_reader):
    """ create a dictionary using the dictreader intput
    """
    data = { k.strip() : [] for k in dict_reader.fieldnames}  # use fieldnames to create a empty dictionary
    for line in dict_reader:  # add data to dictionary
        for k,v in line.items():
            k = k.strip()
            data[k].append(v)

    return data`

Answer (score 2):

`zip` is used to make tuples (name, age)

```
dict = {'name':[], 'age':[]}
for name, age in sorted(zip(mydict['name'], mydict['age'])):
    dict['name'].append(name)
    dict['age'].append(age)
```

output:

```
{'age': [15, 30, 10], 'name': ['andy', 'janice', 'peter']}
```

Comment: you have sorted the tuple, sorting was based on which i.e. "name" or "age"?

Comment: @user2979010 it's based on name.

Answer (score 1):

A two-line version:

```
>>> s = sorted(zip(mydict['name'], mydict['age']))
>>> dict([('name', [x[0] for x in s]), ('age', [x[1] for x in s])])
{'age': [15, 30, 10], 'name': ['andy', 'janice', 'peter']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) ( **for faster performance**) and `zip`- firstly zip `person` to corresponding `age` then sort and after all generate `defaultdict` and dictionary comprehension.

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd= defaultdict(list)
mydict = {'name':['peter', 'janice', 'andy'], 'age':[10, 30, 15]}
d=zip(mydict['name'],mydict['age'])

for i in sorted(d,key=lambda x: x[0]):
    dd['names'].append(i[0])
    dd['age'].append(i[1])
print {k:v for k,v in dd.items()}
```

Output-

```
{'age': [15, 30, 10], 'names': ['andy', 'janice', 'peter']}
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes maybe your approach with the dictionnary isn't the best.Here you're just storing list in a dictionnary. But you may also use a list to store those list. That would be almost the same
What i would suggest first is dict of dict.

```
myPeople = {}
myPeople["peter"] = {"age":20, "country" : "USA"}
myPeople["john"] = {"age":30, "country" : "newzealand"}
myPeople["fred"] = {"age":32, "country" : "France"}
# or if you have only one descript per name to store, 
# you may use only a dict
# myPeopleName["peter"] = 20
# myPeopleName["john"] = 30

#then you iterate the dictionnary as before and the result will be print
# out sorted by key

for k in sorted(myPeople.keys()): 
    print myPeople[k]
```

Edit : My code was totaly wrong. And collection do not sort value by key but preserve the order of the key which you add in the dictionary.